# how to set text view Dynamically over an image in android to support multiple devices with multiple resolutions

Tags: android, html, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I want to set one `textview` over an image, I can use `framelayout` and I can set layout margin, bottom, right and left for the specific place. But the problem is it varies from device to device. The alignment of the `textview` is not proper in all devices because of the screen size. Is there any way to set text view dynamically on image in a specified placement? The image looks like below.. Here I need to set multiple text view to update that value. These all text fields I want to be set dynamically.
Thanks in Advance....

[image]

Comment: What you can do is instead of `ImageView` you can set image in `LinearLayout` or `relativeLayout` then in that layout you can add a `textview` to show text over image.

Comment: Use Relative layout to design your layout if it creates problem send your code